# Where does the uniqueness of the limit fail in this proof if I drop an assumption.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

**Statement**:

> Let $(Z,d), (Y,d')$ be metric spaces and $(X,d)$ a metric subspace of
>   $(Z,d)$ Let $a$ be a limit point of $X$ in $Z$. Let $f: X \to Y$ be a
>   function. If $f$ has limit $b$ for $x$ going to $a$, and $f$ has limit
>   $b'$ for $x$ going to $a$, then $b= b'$

**Proof**:

> Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Choose:
>
> $\delta_1>0: \forall x \in X: (0 <d(x,a) < \delta_1 \implies
>  d'(f(x),b) < \epsilon/2)$ $\delta_2>0: \forall x \in X: (0 <d(x,a) <
>  \delta_2 \implies d'(f(x),b') < \epsilon/2)$
>
> Then, for $x \in X$ such that $0 < d(a,x) < \min\{\delta_1,
>  \delta_2\}$, we have: $d'(b,b') \leq d'(f(x),b) + d'(f(x),b') <
> \epsilon$
>
> Hence, because $\epsilon$ can be made as small as desired, it follows
>   that $d(b,b') = 0$, which means $b = b'$, as desired.

My question:

> Where does this proof fail when we drop the hypothesis that $a$ is a
>   limit point of $X$?

Comment: To start: ​ Have you found spaces and a function for which that will fail? ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "For $x\in X$ such that $d(x,a)<\dots$." The fact that there *exists* such an $x\in X$ depends exactly on $a$ being a limit point of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ isn't a limit point of $X$, then we can't find approach $a$ by elements of $x$. So a ball around $a$ will be $Z-X$ eventually (as we make the radius smaller) and then we can't map element from it by $f$, as the domain of $f$ is $X$

In fact it doesn't change anything fundamental in the way you prove the statement. It just gives us that the $f(x)$ is well-defined for $x \to a$.

Comment: Yes in principle. But he asked where a certain proof failed, and that proof didn't explicitly mention any sequences, so this isn't _explcitly_ an answer to the question..

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yeah, you're right I was thrown off by the $x \to a$ a bit and I assumed it's a sequence. I fixed it now.